# Activity A calling B and B calling C, Need C to send data back to A

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a main activity that calls another(2nd) activity "VennDiagram"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VennDiagram.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
```

the 2nd activity after doing some calculations calls a 3rd activity "ImageMapTest...." acitvity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageMapTestActivity.class);
i.putExtras(sendBundle);
startActivity(i);
//finish();
```

Now I need help to return the an arrayList from the 3rd activity to the first ??!!

```
 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidClientActivity.class);
 in.putExtra("songList", playList);
 setResult(200, in);
 finish();
```

I do have an intent listener as below at my 1st activity, but its just that the 3rd activity won't send it back to it

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100 || resultCode == 200)
     {
           }
```

P.S I did read couple of similar posts but they were not what I was looking for...

Comment: as you can see from my 3rd activity I DO call the first activity "androidClienctActivity" but it doesn't work and just returns to 2nd one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just send the result received by B from C back to A.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, data);

 setResult(resultCode,resultData);

 finish();
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to jump from C to A ? you have to take the same root back C->B->A ? This might show activity B's Screen briefly too ?

Comment: This won't show B's screen since B is finished in the onActivityResult function. B will only be shown after executing onActivityResult. But since finish() is called, B is not shown.

Comment: So when should I finish() B ? cz finish() is commented out in my code for activity B. and if a class is finish() can they still wait for onActivityResult ?

Comment: You should finish B as soon as you set your return result for A.

Answer (score 1):

Finish C and return your array to B, and then when you return to B finish and return the result back to A.

Comment: So there is no way to jump from C to A ? you have to take the same root back C->B->A ? This might show activity B's Screen briefly too ?

Comment: I don't believe there is. Activities are on a stack, so you can't just jump from C to A. It shouldn't show B, though. In my experience, it jumps right past it without flashing the screen. This might be because it processes OnActivityResult before anything else.